# F# - nested pipelines

Tags: f#

I'm at the moment reading the book "Real world functional programming", and wondering how I can write something like:

```
let numbers = [ 1 .. 10 ]
let isOdd(n) = (n%2 = 1)
let square(n) = n * n

let myList = 
    numbers 
    |> List.map square 
        |> List.iter(printfn "%d")
    |> List.filter isOdd 
        |> List.iter(printfn "%d")
```

The code I've posted will fail after the First List.iter() with a message that says:

> Type mismatch. Expecting a     unit ->
>   'a     but given a     'b list -> 'b
>   list     The type 'unit' does not
>   match the type ''a list'

How can I do something like above (just where it will work)?

Comment: let isOdd(n) is Boolean and your other declarations are integer. Why should it like it?

Comment: @Carnotaurus - I want to first map all the ints in the List to the method `square` - and then afterwards it should take the list of numbers once again and get all odd numbers..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `List.map` instead of `List.iter`, and return the elements unchanged. You would be rebuilding the list:

```
let myList =
    numbers
    |> List.map square
    |> List.map (fun x -> printfn "%d" x; x)
    |> List.filter isOdd
    |> List.map (fun x -> printfn "%d" x; x)
```

Another way would be, to instead of storing each element separatly, is to store the whole list as a function parameter:

```
let myList =
    numbers
    |> List.map square
    |> (fun xs -> List.iter (printfn "%d") xs; xs)
    |> List.filter isOdd
    |> (fun xs -> List.iter (printfn "%d") xs; xs)
```

One last variant I can think of, is to completely branch the pipeline:

```
let myList =
    numbers
    |> List.map square
    |> fun xs ->
          xs |> List.iter (printfn "%d")
          xs
          |> List.filter isOdd
          |> fun xs ->
                xs |> List.iter (printfn "%d")
                xs
```

Comment: Your first option could be made prettier by extending the List module with a method, I'd call it 'do'. Then there's no need to remember to return the value. ´List.map square |> List.do (printfn "%d")´

Comment: I think the last variant is a bit crazy anti-pattern. You're just emulating `let xs = <e1> in <e2>` with `<e1> |> fun xs -> <e2>` which is not a good idea in a language that provides `let` keyword :-) (It is a nice trick in pure lambda calculus though)